# nginx reverse proxy chain: redirect http to https

Tags: docker, nginx, reverse-proxy

one nginx server is exposed to the internet and redirects the traffic.
A second nginx server is only available internally and listens to port 6880 (bookstack (a wiki) is hosted via docker).

In the local network, everything is unencrypted, while to the outside only https via port 443 is available.

The application (bookstack) works fine in the local network (http).
When accessing the application from the outside via https, the page is displayed, but all links are http instead of https. (For example, *http://.../logo.png* is in the login page's source code, but *https://.../logo.png* would be correct.)

Where and how do i switch to https?

**First server sites-enabled/bookstack** (already contains the redirect to https):

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name bookstack.example.org;
return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
listen 443 ssl;
server_name bookstack.example.org;
ssl_certificate         /etc/letsencrypt/live/<...>/cert.pem;
ssl_certificate_key     /etc/letsencrypt/live/<...>/privkey.pem;
location / {
    try_files index index.html $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @bookstack;
}
location @bookstack {
    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_set_header   X-FORWARDED_PROTO https;
    proxy_set_header   Host              bookstack.example.org;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://<internal ip>:6880;
    }
}
```

**Second server sites-enabled/bookstack:**

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
server_name bookstack.example.org;
index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;
location /  {
    proxy_pass         http://<local docker container ip>:6880;
    proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

The docker container also deploys its own nginx config, but i didn't touch that one yet.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Above nginx settings should work. The issue was with the docker container still using the wrong APP_URL. Running the artisan update script (bookstackapp.com/docs/admin/commands) did not suffice, but reinstalling the docker container did it.